# Can't see any servers on Minecraft Java Edition Win10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

Everytime I go to multiplayer on Minecraft Java Edition for Windows 10, it starts scanning but it doesnt stop, not showing any results for multiplayer games.

If I do a direct connection, it works though.
Can anyone explain why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: The list only shows servers you've added to the list. It doesn't magically bring up all existing servers.

Comment: So first you need to add some. I was expecting to see some suggestions. The message is not clear. Something like "No servers added to this list. Please direct connect some and they will be presented here"

Comment: The 'scanning part' would bring up servers that are in the same network as you. Including single player worlds, that you opened yourself in another running instance of minecraft. But this is usually not the case.

Answer (score 1):

When you click Multiplayer, it will show you the list of servers that you have manually saved to the list. You see the 'Scanning' message because it is looking for worlds that are open to LAN (on your home network).

You can add Minecraft servers to the list using 'Add Server' so that you can quickly connect to these again in the future, without needing to enter the IP every time.